# In Magento 2 how to print Product view page?

Tags: magento2.3.0, print, product-view-page

In magento 2.3.0 how to print product view page ?
i tried o using **window.print()** but its shown like below image url.
http://prntscr.com/n4i0si

but i need only the product data will be print like below image

http://prntscr.com/n4i2lb

any one help on this

My code in .phtml

```
<div class="product-addto-links addto-links" data-role="add-to-links">
    <a id="print-icon" class="action" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Print Product" data-original-title="Print Product">Print Product</a>
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(){
        window.print();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: I think you can print specific page only

Comment: yes.but its print header and footer also.i don't need header and footer.i need to only print product data 
and updated question with my code

Comment: I know, check this https://jsfiddle.net/jdavidzapatab/6sctvg2z/

Comment: tried this but its display like this url
http://prntscr.com/n4ifjc

Comment: better if you post the whole code you tried

Comment: var prtContent = document.getElementsByClassName("main-container")[0];
    var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
    
    //WinPrint.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">');
    
    
    WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
    WinPrint.document.close();
    WinPrint.setTimeout(function(){
      WinPrint.focus();
      WinPrint.print();
      WinPrint.close();
    }, 1000);

Comment: i tried above code

Comment: try this one | function printData()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printcontent");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}

printData();

Comment: if you want to add custom style for this, create a new window then add your own styles like this -  : divToPrint.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
    divToPrint.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" />');
    divToPrint.document.write('</head><body >');
    divToPrint.document.write(data);
    divToPrint.document.write('</body></html>');

Answer (score 1):

i got  solution:

we can write below code in our CSS file we can hide header footer in `window.print()`:

```
@media print {
    #header,#footer {display: none;}
}
```